# Notnull variable become nullable after transpiling kotlin to java

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable, transpiler

when I have a kotlin class like that one suppose that uniqueName is NotNull.

```
data class Payload(
        @SerializedName("unique_name") val uniqueName: String, 
        @SerializedName("nbf") val nbf: Int, 
        @SerializedName("exp") val exp: Int, 
        @SerializedName("iat") val iat: Int
)
```

but when i tested this code

```
    @Test
    fun fromStringJsonToObject4() {
        val gsonHelper = GsonHelper()
        val payloadJsonString = "{}"
        val payload = Payload("", 0, 0, 0)

        assertEquals(gsonHelper.fromStringJsonToObject(payloadJsonString, Payload::class.java), payload)
    }
```

it returns

```
Expected :Payload(uniqueName=null, nbf=0, exp=0, iat=0)
Actual   :Payload(uniqueName=, nbf=0, exp=0, iat=0)
```

so how uniqueName in my object become nullable ??

Comment: this is because gson is write by Java rater than Kotlin. so the non-nullable checking is disabled when create instance doesn't through constructor than in native ways.

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
gsonHelper.fromStringJsonToObject(payloadJsonString, Payload::class.java)
```

delegates to the low-level, unspecified `Unsafe.allocateInstance()` call, which allocates an object without calling any constructors. It then uses reflection to write the fields. This circumvents the barrier where Kotlin is supposed to establish its static typing invariants: the assertions in the constructor code.

This is why the object creation will succeed and invalidate Kotlin's static proofs about the object. A non-null property will end up with a null value.

You should avoid using not-nullable properties for objects created through reflection by Java libraries that are not aware of Kotlin's nullability rules. This will let the Kotlin side start from a valid point and then the compiler will guide you through the usual ceremony of lifting nullable to not-nullable values as required.

Answer (score 0):

It's not nullable: if you try to access the `uniqueName` field you will get a NPE.

Gson does not know about nullable/nonnullable properties, and will use default values for missing entries. Your json does not contain `unique_name`, and the default value for `String` is `null`.

Comment: "Not nullable" means "you'll never get an NPE on access".